# Having difficulties with checkboxes

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular6

What am I doing wrong?

(Angular 6)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbqylr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I have below my table, where, in the thead, there is a master checkbox, which, if clicked, selects all the checkboxes in the table.

```
 <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="selectAllCb($event.checked)"></mat-checkbox></th>
                        <th>Nº Protocolo</th>
                        <th>Resumo</th>
                        <th>Interessado</th>
                        <th>Tipo</th>
                        <th>Data Cadastro</th>
                        <th>Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let documento of documentos, let i = index">
                        <td><mat-checkbox [ngModel]="selectAll"(change)="onChangeCheckBox($event.checked,documento?.id)"></mat-checkbox>
                            </td>
                        <td id="codigo">{{documento?.codigo}}/{{documento?.ano}}</td>
                        <td id="resumo">{{documento?.resumo}}</td>
                        <td id="interessado">{{documento?.interessado}}</td>
                        <td id="tipo">{{documento?.tipoDocumento?.nome}}</td>
                        <td id="data">{{documento?.dataCadastro | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
                        <td id="acoes">
                            <div class="row">
                                <button class="badge badge-light" [routerLink]="['/documentos/detalhe/',documento?.id]">
                                    <i class="material-icons" title="Editar protocolo">edit</i>
                                </button>
                                <button class="badge badge-light" (click)="gerarEtiqueta(documento?.id)">
                                    <i class="material-icons" title="Imprimir Etiqueta">print</i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

the master checkbox set a selectAll: boolean property, which is used by the checkboxes of the rest of the table, through [ngModel]. The checkboxes generated by ngfor, when clicked, pass values ​​to the component.

```
export class DocumentosComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  selectAll: boolean = false;
constructor(){}

ngOnInit() {}

 selectAllCb(isChecked: boolean) { 
      this.selectAll = isChecked;

  }
}
```

However, when the value of the checkboxes is changed by the property bind, the change event is not triggered.

Comment: https://angular-jbqylr.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Might Be, $event.checked is returning undefined. Try not operator.

```
selectAllCb(state: boolean){
    console.log('called', state);
    this.selectAll = !this.selectAll;
}
```

If that still not works. You can call CD manually.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){} 
this.cd.markForCheck();
```